# Nonsensical MethodError in nested dict?

Tags: dictionary, error-handling, nested, julia

While translating a program from python to julia I stumbled upon this error and I can't wrap my head around it. Here's a simplification of the snippet:

```
a = Dict()
for x in 1:3
   a[x] = Dict((x,) => 1//1)     #the keys of the nested dicts must all be tuples
   println("Insert numbers for "$(x)": ")
   for y in 1:3
       while !(haskey(a[x],(y,)))
           print("$((y,)): ")
           a[x][y] = rationalize(convert(Float64,eval(parse(readline(STDIN)))))
       end
   end
end
```

When I run this I get:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Tuple{Int64}}, ::Int64)
```

which seems nonsensical to me because I'm not converting an int to a tuple, but I'm converting a Numeric to a Rational and then I assign it to a key which happens to be a tuple.
What's the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is happening on the try to convert `y` (`Int64`) to a *Tuple* type.

You could correct it changing to `(y,)`:

```
a[x][(y,)] = rationalize(convert(Float64,eval(parse(readline(STDIN)))))
```

After changing this line, the execution gives me the following output:

```
Insert numbers for 1:
(2,): 2.3
(3,): 4//5
Insert numbers for 2:
(1,): 9/7
(3,): 3.141592653
Insert numbers for 3:
(1,): 3.33333
(2,): 2
```

And adding a `dump(a)` at the end of the code, the output:

```
Dict{Any,Any} len 3
  2: Dict{Tuple{Int64},Rational{Int64}} len 3
    (3,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 199345706
      den: Int64 63453709
    (2,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 1
      den: Int64 1
    (1,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 9
      den: Int64 7
  3: Dict{Tuple{Int64},Rational{Int64}} len 3
    (3,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 1
      den: Int64 1
    (2,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 2
      den: Int64 1
    (1,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 333333
      den: Int64 100000
  1: Dict{Tuple{Int64},Rational{Int64}} len 3
    (3,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 4
      den: Int64 5
    (2,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 23
      den: Int64 10
    (1,): Rational{Int64}
      num: Int64 1
      den: Int64 1
```

One more thing is the first `println`. Maybe it should be:

```
println("Insert numbers for $(x): ")
```

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.4.3</sub>